# display received message android

Tags: java, android, sms, message

im trying to create a dummy app that increments/decrements a number but in the background it is listening to any recieved messages , im unable to to display any received messages in the app, heres my code for the smsReceiver class.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

/* Class used to listen for incoming SMS Messages */
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        String msgBody ="";
        if (bundle != null){
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                   // msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                     msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();//.toString();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (root.canWrite()){
            File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bonbon info");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File f = new File(dir, "test.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            out.write(msgBody);
            out.close();
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }                      





}
}
```

i have also added this to my manifest for receiving .

```
  `<receiver android:name=".listener.SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

and this for permission

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />`

error im getting is .

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver cps633.lab4.listener.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cps633.lab4.listener.SMSReceiver

Comment: How are you registering the Receiver? Please post your manifest.

Comment: Did you add the appropriate permissions to your app?

Comment: @MikeM. i have edit the post to include the manifest

Comment: @NathanWalters yes i had done that, ive added my manifest to the op

Comment: Your Receiver class is named `SMSReceiver`, but you have `SmsListener` in the manifest.

Comment: @MikeM. Yea, i fixed that, but the app still crashes

Comment: If it's crashing, your logcat will show you the errors/exceptions and where they're happening. If you need help deciphering it, you'll have to post it as well.

Comment: @MikeM. ive posted the error, says class not found

Comment: Is `SMSReceiver.java` in a folder named `listener`? That's what `".listener.SMSReceiver"` indicates. If not, remove `.listener`. (For future reference, I just want to point out that you might need to post much more of your logcat. In this case, however, that one line just happened to be sufficient.)